# How to figure out what the current system preferred language is

Tags: python, string, macos, localization

Is there an easy way to get the preferred language on a system? I am writing an application that has to support different language, but needs to pick what language to display based on the system language. Is there a way in python to figure out what the current system language is, or is the only option to use some PyObjC with standard mac interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's pretty easy to do using PyObjC

```
>>> import objc
>>> from Cocoa import NSUserDefaults
>>> defs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
>>> langs = defs.objectForKey_("AppleLanguages")
>>> preferred_lang = langs.objectAtIndex_(0)
>>> print preferred_lang
en
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the python [locale module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html)

Simple example below

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: if i change my preferred language in system preferences, this will still return en_US. I need to figure out what the preferred language is from the system preferences